# Plotting temporal TS and omitting NA data

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to plot some temporal data that have some gaps in them. You can see the plot here: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=da222e2.
The problem is that during the time gaps in the TS the line plot is interpolated over the gap and I don't want it to. I've tried interleaving the gaps with an NA flag, but there are around 10000 datapoints sorted from multiple files, that makes it difficult to add the NA flag manually. If it's not possible to define the behaviour of the plot(0function, is there another plot I can use, e.g. zoo, that will allow me to not have the lines drawn between the gaps?

Comment: some sample code would be useful...

Comment: You're right joris. the reason I didn't include it was because I was thinking that it could be a parameter in a plotting function that I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

It's not difficult to interleave the gaps with NA using merge, once you know the sequence of your time series. A little demonstration :

```
X <- c(1:20,41:100)
Y <- rnorm(80)

plot(X,Y,type="l")    

Z <- seq(min(X),max(X),by=1)    # I take 1 is the period.
newData <- merge(data.frame(X,Y),data.frame(X=Z),all=T)
plot(newData,type="l")
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a zoo series with a gap.  Then define `g` which includes the time points of z plus the missing points.  Create a zero width zoo series to merge with `z` and plot.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(rnorm(12), c(1:6, 11:16)) # test data

g <- seq(start(z), end(z), 1)
zz <- merge(z, zoo(, g))
plot(zz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who contributed to my query.

I also posted this question to the R-help mail list and it's from there that I was answered with a procedure that worked in filling in the missing data points with an NA flag. The problem was that the time-stamps were irregularly spaced, but still within certain thresholds.

For posterity purposes this is the suggestion by Duncan Murdoch:

> Any software is going to have the same problem you had:  how do you
>   define a gap?  If the definition is something simple like "time
>   difference greater than X", then it will be fairly easy:  use diff()
>   to find all the time differences in the sorted times, and wherever
>   those exceed X, insert a new data point with an NA value.  For
>   example:

```
t <- c(1,2,3,7,8,9,11,12,13)
x <- rnorm(length(T))
d <- diff(t)
gap <- which(d > 1.5)
if (length(gap)) {
   newT <- (t[gap] + t[gap+1])/2
   t <- c(t, newT)
   x <- c(x, rep(NA, length(newT)))
   o <- order(t)
   t <- t[o]
   x <- x[o]
}
plot(t, x, type='l')
```